# WebSphere MQ FTE Agent Directory does not exist?

Tags: ibm-mq, websphere-mq-fte

When I tried to start an FTE agent in the command prompt , it displays the error message as "An internal error has occurred. Unable to complete the command because the agent directory does not exist".

What would be the reason for this? It was working fine until yesterday. And is there any way to start an agent in MQ FTE itself? I use fteStartAgent in command prompt each time to start an agent.

Kindly advise me on this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few possible reasons for this.  It is possible that the default properties were changed and now point to an invalid location.  This usually happens when the different components are installed and you select to provide the connection details again rather than to reuse the existing configuration.

Another possibility is that the default properties have been changed to point to a different Coordination QMgr.  Sometimes people want to run Prod and Dev agents on the same host and set up connectivity to more than one Coordination QMgr.  The result is that the default properties can point to only one at a time and so some agent directories are found while others are not.  The trick to making this work is to use the -P option to select the proper Coordination QMgr.